# SQL declare variable for a long and repetitive select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, declare

I want to declare a variable and do the following :

```
Select     
cast (SUM(case when @Dummy is not null then 1 else 0 end)*1.0/443321 as decimal(10,5)) @Dummy    
FROM hellotable
WHERE @Dummy in ("100 different field names in hellotable")
```

However this is not working... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: basically i can copy and paste the same select over 100 times with different field names, but i dont think this is a good way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing that by Dynamic SQL..

```
DECLARE @dummy sysname
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT  CAST (SUM(CASE WHEN '+ @Dummy +N' IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                  END) * 1.0 / 443321 AS DECIMAL(10, 5)) '+ @Dummy +N'     
                FROM    hellotable
                WHERE   '+ @Dummy +N'  IN ( '' )'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. but there is the error :Must declare the scalar variable "@SQL".

Answer (score 0):

Try using temp tables to populate these with data and then user inner join with your main table instead of using IN in WHERE clause.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (FieldFromHelloTable nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES ('value1'),('value2'),('value3'),('value4'),('value5')

SELECT * --this is oversimplified to ilustrate the point and you can modify this further
FROM HelloTable H
inner join #TempTable Tmp on H.SomeField = Tmp.FieldFromHelloTable
```